# Secret Santa Name Generator by someone in way over her head

Tags: javascript

Restarting here because I think I'm a bit confusing :)

here's what's going on - I am creating a 'secret santa' generator. my family does a thing where the four of us do a four-way gift exchange, with three categories, lets call them A, B, and C. We all give a gift in each category to our family members, and receive a gift from each category from our family members, so 12 gifts are exchanged in all. I need to create a generator that will allow me to sort out who is gifting for who.

I currently have an array with all four names. It selects a name, and spits it out. My plan is, since I've figured out some of the logistics, to have one large if-then statement. if the first person gets their own name, restart until they don't. If it's not a match, move on to the 'then.' The then will move to the next person. If their generation is their own name, restart. if it matches the name generated for the last person, restart. etc, until we get all the way to the end.

I am a COMPLETE NOVICE. I've never coded before! But I didn't think it would be all that hard? Please help!!

Comment: `and without erasing banana` why do you need that limitation? `that says if I get banana again, rerun the code` choosing randomly that way could theoretically mean that you program never terminates.

Comment: Consider using `fruitArr.includes(someOtherFruit);` in your `if` statement. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: Am I right in thinking that (0) everyone receives an(exactly one) A, a B and a C and that (1) everyone buys an(exactly one) A, a B and a C?

Answer (score 0):

To check that you haven't chosen the same option again, you're going to need to keep track of which options you've chosen already. There are essentially three ways you can go about that:

1. Keep a separate array of chosen options, and each time you choose something you check if it exists in that array. If it does, choose again.
2. Keep a separate array of options that haven't been chosen, and only choose from this array.
3. You can look at the problem instead as randomly sorting your fruit array, then just walking through it to pick each option.

Here's some example code for how you might go about each option:

1. You can use [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add objects to an array, and [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to see if an element exists in an array.

```js
const fruit = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'peach'];

const chosenFruit = [];

const chooseFruit = function () {
    if (fruit.length === chosenFruit.length) {
        // If all fruit have been chosen, a new one can't be picked
        return null;
    }

    // First, pick an option
    const seed = Math.random();
    const choiceIndex = Math.floor(fruit.length * seed);
    let choice = fruit[choiceIndex];

    // Then, see if your option has been picked before
    if (chosenFruit.includes(choice)) {
        // Calling this function recursively like this will guarantee an unchosen option,
        // but you can't know how many attempts it will take
        choice = chooseFruit();
    } else {
        // If you've chosen a new option, remember it
        chosenFruit.push(choice);
    }
    return choice;
};

console.log(chooseFruit());
console.log(chooseFruit());
console.log(chooseFruit());
console.log(chooseFruit());
console.log(chooseFruit());
```

2. You can clone an array of primitive values, like strings, using the [Array constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array) and [rest parameter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), and [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) can be used to remove objects from an array.

```js
const fruit = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'peach'];

const unchosenFruit = new Array(...fruit);

const chooseFruit = function () {
    if (unchosenFruit.length === 0) {
        // If all fruit have been chosen, a new one can't be picked
        return null;
    }

    // First, pick an option
    const seed = Math.random();
    const choiceIndex = Math.floor(unchosenFruit.length * seed);
    const choice = unchosenFruit[choiceIndex];

    // Then, remove that option from the unchosenFruit array
    unchosenFruit.splice(choiceIndex, 1);

    return choice;
};

console.log(chooseFruit());
console.log(chooseFruit());
console.log(chooseFruit());
console.log(chooseFruit());
console.log(chooseFruit());
```

3. You can randomly sort an array by first creating an array of the same length that's filled with random values. Then, copy that array and sort the copy using [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). You can then use the relationship between those two arrays to randomly sort your initial array.

```js
const fruit = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'peach'];

const randomArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {
    randomArray.push(Math.random());
}
const randomArraySorted = (new Array(...randomArray)).sort();

const unchosenFruit = (new Array(...fruit)).sort((a, b) => {
    let iA = fruit.indexOf(a);
    let iB = fruit.indexOf(b);

    let randA = randomArray[iA];
    let randB = randomArray[iB];

    let newIA = randomArraySorted.indexOf(randA);
    let newIB = randomArraySorted.indexOf(randB);

    return newIB - newIA;
});

const chooseFruit = function () {
    if (unchosenFruit.length === 0) {
        // If all fruit have been chosen, a new one can't be picked
        return null;
    }

    // Here, picking an option is as easy as picking the first option
    const choice = unchosenFruit[0];

    // Then, we just remove the first option
    unchosenFruit.splice(0, 1);

    return choice;
};

console.log(chooseFruit());
console.log(chooseFruit());
console.log(chooseFruit());
console.log(chooseFruit());
console.log(chooseFruit());
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I see the problem is:
Let's say the 4 family members are Dad, Mom, Kid1, Kid2.
Each family member is to buy 1 each of (A, B, C),
and give it to some other family member, such that each
receives 1 each of (A, B, C).

The simplest way to do that, I believe, is set up a generic
chart of giving A's, B's, C's and then randomly assign the
four people to it.

```
Each row will represent a 'giver', and each column, a 'receiver'
....  P1  P2  P3  P4
P1     X   A   B   C .... this means P1 gives (A -> P2, B -> P3, C -> P4)
P2     B   X   C   A .... X denotes no gifts to oneself
P3     A   C   X   B
P4     C   B   A   X
```

Now just randomly assign Dad, Mom, Kid1, Kid2 as P1 - P4.
There are lots of ways of doing that - you just want a random permutation of 4 things.

You **could** then just draw names out of a hat: first name is P1, second is P2, etc.  Or if you must go high-tech ...

One way would be put the family members in an array, and randomly exchange pairs (for a while), and then the final order gives who is P1, P2, P3, P4

```
 let family = [ "Dad", "Mom", "Kid1", "Kid2" ];
 let i; let family_size = family.length;
 for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
   {
    // choose two members at random (doesn't matter if they're the same)
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * family_size);
    let k = Math.floor(Math.random() * family_size);
    // switch them
    let t = family[j];
    family[j] = family[k];
    family[k] = t;
   }

// Now family array is in some random order:
// P1 is family[0], P2 is family[1]
```

Here is another way:

```
  let family = 
     [ Math.random() + " Mom", 
       Math.random() + " Dad", 
       Math.random() + " Kid1",
       Math.random() + " Kid2" ];
 
   family.sort();
   // Now just use whatever order family is in ... ignore the numbers
```